# sitemap for non-CMS based website

Tags: php, wordpress, url, sitemap

I've just finished a new version of my website but now I don't know how to generate a correct sitemap.
Now the website is based on `PHP` files and folder and in blog folder there is Wordpress.
This is ho my tree structure looks like:

```
index.php  
about.php  
contact.php  
support/index.php  
support/faq.php  
blog/  
and so on...
```

On Wordpress I can generate the sitemap automatically but how can I include the others link like `about.php` etc.?
Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate Wordpress sitemap automatically - in /blog/ folder.

Periodically and manually you can make sitemap for your site at http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ if you do not update it so often.

That is simple solution, and the problem is: in your "site sitemap" will be links from your site + links from your blog.

If you have dedicated server, try [Google Sitemap Generator](http://code.google.com/p/googlesitemapgenerator/), but be careful - periodically download and review links in sitemap. Google Sitemap Generator can include 404 links but I do not why, I just removed it.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of sites/tools that can be used to generate sitemaps for you. These can be used on any site - one created manually or one created by a CMS such as Wordpress.

I won't recommend one as a) each one has it's merits and b) what's a good one now won't necessary be the "best" in a few months or years time.

Google has one in it's Webmaster Tools - which is probably as good as any, but I don't know whether it can cope with a mixed site.

A search for "sitemap generator" will bring back a list of others.

Comment: Thanks but should I have one sitemap for wordpress and one for the rest of the site or only one sitemap with all the links?

Comment: @matteodv - You should really only have one sitemap. There should be one of these tools that can work with a mixed site. I'll make that clear in the answer.